# How to call a function defined inside react component in a typescript class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-component

```
 export class abc extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
    function(name: string) {
    console.log("I wish to call this function"+ name);
    }

render() {
    return (
      <div>Hello</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now I wish to call the function method of the above-defined component into another xyz.ts class (which is not a react component) is it possible to do the same?

Comment: One way is to pass your function to a child component as a prop.

Comment: this function has no name. How would you call this? Also, calling that from a function defined in another non-component class sounds strange to me. Could you clarify what you want to do?

Comment: If the function allows it (and, if you need to use it into a different component, this is very likely), you could move it outside the class component and export it separately: `export function foo() { ... }; export class MyClass extends React.Component { ... };`.

Comment: The function is with a name and I wish to call that function to update a value of the component class from a non-component class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the listener pattern like this:

```
export interface IListener {
    notify: (name:string) => void;
}


export class Listener {
    listener : IListener[] = [];


    addListener(listener: IListener) {
      this.listener.add(listener)
    }

    notifyListener() {
      this.listener.forEach((listener) => {
          listener.notify("abc");
      });
    }
  }

  export class abc extends React.Component<IProps, IState> implements IListener {

    componentDidMount() {
        // register this class as a listener
        new Listener().addListener(this);
    }

    public notify(name:string) {
        this.test(name);
    }

    test(name: string) {
      console.log("I wish to call this function"+ name);
    }
    render() {
      return (
      <div>Hello</div>);
    }
    
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely move the function out of the component and export it if you want to use it in a different ts file.